# Need to get file I/O feature in WebExtensions

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a WebExtensions addon. I need to access the file system in order to read/write from a file. I have explored WebExtensions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions

but can't find any such API. Is it possible? or anybody did a workaround?

Comment: Ok. I just managed to do a workaround by using Window's clipboard (through jquery) and then getting that clipboard text from my c# application. The application then takes care of the process of creating the CSV. Not a one-platform solution but anyways it seems to work. But I'm a bit disappointed with WebExtensions' inability to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your use case allows you to just use the storage API, for file system access, you have to use [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging). This will still require your users to install a separate executable provided by you (in addition to the add-on code which can communicate with the executable).

You might take a look at my extension [webappfind](https://github.com/brettz9/webappfind), though it is currently OSX only, for an idea on how to do so (mine uses Node.js). It isn't super easy, but at least NativeMessaging provides a way to do so.